# UIScrollView and -[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:]

Tags: ios, uikit, nsrunloop

I am working on a UI test framework (KIF-next) which runs in the main thread of the application.  The basic process is:

1. Perform some test logic.
2. Spin the main loop for 0.1 seconds via `runUntilDate:`.
3. Repeat.

This method works incredibly well. You can simulate click events, you can swipe across sliders, watch alert views animate in and out, scrollToRowAtIndexPath:.  Everything works well except one specific scenario, dragging scroll views.

You can drag the scroll view up and down but when you release your finger, nothing happens.  Moreover, touch events are no longer recognized by other views and all you can do is drag the scrollview around.

If this execution pattern ends and the code exits, the scroll views will do their bounce/deceleration, but this isn't an option as I am working in ocunit which performs sequential execution.

My questions: **Why is this happening and what can be done to correct it?**

I have two demos:

#### Demo 1: Block your whole application

With this code, you can test out your application and confirm that everything is fine until your scroll.  After that, nothing works.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        while (YES) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.25]];
        }
    });
    return YES;
}
```

#### Demo 2: Block temporarily

If you wire this code to a button, you will see the same effect as above if your first tap the button and then scroll. Once the timer completes, you will see your application spring back to life.

```
- (IBAction)spinButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
}
```

Comment: I *think* you've run into a run loop modes problem. It sounds like the run loop is entering `UITrackingRunLoopMode` but not exiting it?

Comment: Thanks @DaveDeLong.  After some digging (and learning about modes), the problem was that I was never entering `UITrackingRunLoopMode` because it is in the nested run loop I created.  Normally when tracking starts, it stops the outer run loop and starts it again in a new mode, but the outer run loop was never able to exit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, as Dave pointed out, has to do with run loop modes.  Applications will reside mainly in the `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode` mode but switch into `UITrackingRunLoopMode` when the user starts scrolling and back again when the scroll view finishes decelerating.  This appears to be to prevent normal timers from firing during scrolling.  (You can see this in Safari where animations stop updating during scroll.)

The mechanics appear to be as follows.

1. The `UIApplication` has a stack to keep track of the current run loop mode requested by the application.
2. When the application starts up, it calls `GSEventRunModal` which in turn calls `CFRunLoopRunInMode` with the current run mode for the application, `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`.
3. When the user starts swiping a scroll view, the scroll view specific pan gesture recognizer enters the Began state and triggers `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] pushRunMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode requester:self]`.
4. This method pushes the string onto the stack, sees that the run mode is different, and calls `CFRunLoopStop` on the run loop created by `GSEventRunModal`.
5. `GSEventRunModal` loops and calls `CFRunLoopRunInMode` again, this time with `UITrackingRunLoopMode`.
6. When deceleration completes, the gesture recognizer calls `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] popRunMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode requester:self]` and similar steps take place.

The problem with my long running function that calls `runUntilDate:` it never terminates so `CFRunLoopStop` has no effect.  One approach to take would be to swizzle `pushRunMode:requester:` and `popRunMode:requester:` and do something similar with my own internal logic.

The approach I've actually taken, since I will not be receiving any actual user interaction, is to send the touch move event to the application and check to see what gestureRecognizers are on it.  If there is a `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer` that entered the `Began` phase, the remainder of the run loops for dragging are done with `UITrackingRunLoopMode`.  Once the touch simulation is complete, I continue to run in that mode until `scrollView.dragging == NO`.

You can see it in action at https://github.com/bnickel/KIF/blob/kif-next/Additions/UIView-KIFAdditions.m#L368